# how to check if shared memory is empty?

Tags: c, null, shared-memory, coredump

I've a project using shared memory, and i have a while-loop reading from it every time, thus i want to check that it's empty.
the code for opening shared memory using:

```
key_t key;
int shmid;
if ((key = ftok("ex31.c", 'k')) == -1){
    perror("ftok");
    exit(1);}
if ((shmid = shmget(key, 3, FLAGS)) == -1) {
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);}
char* shmaddr;
if( shmaddr=shmat(shmid,0,0) == (char*)-1){
    printf("error in attaching to the shared memory\n");
    exit(0);}
if(shmaddr==NULL) /// THROWS EXCEPTION!!
```

it gives me error:

```
 segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

..HELP?

Comment: Please give us an example we can actually compile and try to get the same result as you did.

Comment: #define FLAGS IPC_CREAT | 0644   maybe this piece of code coud help, beyond that there's nothing else to show

Comment: If you don't have a debugger, printf() each line so that you can determine which instruction (if any) actually caused the seg-fault.  Right now, it could be within any one of your functions.  The (core dumped) output, if it has memory and registers and other goodies like a stack trace, could also really help out.  If the error is occuring on the if statement, print out shmaddr beforehand to see if you indeed have access to it and it isn't garbage.

Comment: I would also compile with warnings enabled. I see at least one place which should generate a warning and this may help you as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have a quick look at *this* complete program and see what happens when you run it twice, first with an argument of `-1`, then again with an argument of `42`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    if (i = atoi (argv[1]) == -1)
        printf ("   WAS negative one: %d\n", i);
    else
        printf ("   was NOT negative one: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

The transcript is as follows:

```
pax> ./testprog -1
   WAS negative one: 0
pax> ./testprog 42
   was NOT negative one: 1
```

You can see there that, even though it detects the `atoi` value correctly, `i` appears not to be set correctly after the comparison.

If you look at your code, you already *know* (or soon *will* know, once you finish reading this answer) how to solve this problem. Compare your errant line with one of the others (both slightly reformatted to make it obvious):

```
if  ((shmid   = shmget (key, 3, FLAGS)) == -1       ) {
if   (shmaddr = shmat  (shmid, 0, 0  )  == (char*)-1) {
//  ^                                 ^
//   \_______extra parentheses_______/
```

The reason the second line doesn't work as you expect is because `==` has a *higher* precedence than `=`. That means that the first line does what you want but the second is *effectively:*

```
if (shmaddr = (shmat (shmid, 0, 0) == (char*)-1) ) {
//  \          \________higher________________/ /
//   \____________________lower________________/
```

As you can see, that precedence rule means that the expression `shmat (shmid, 0, 0) == (char*)-1` is evaluated first and then the result of that (`1` for true or `0` for false) is assigned to `shmaddr`. Both those values are *very* unlikely to be a valid memory address so is almost certainly causing a crash when you try to dereference it<sup>(a)</sup>.

The line you need should match the format of the other two, with parentheses around the assignment to ensure it's done first:

```
if ((shmaddr = shmat (shmid, 0, 0)) == (char*)-1)) {
// ^                              ^
//  \__________add these_________/
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The case of `1` being assigned is irrelevant for your case since that means the `if` condition evaluated true and your program will exit. Hence, the *only* pathway to the code that tries to dereference `shmaddr` will have it set to 0.